# Controlling Google Chrome using Java

Tags: java, firefox, google-chrome

I was looking for a way to control google chrome or firefox or internet explorer using java.

Say like I simply call a function passing the URL as the parameter and the page will be loaded.

I'm writing a java program that I can use to automatically save files on server so that I don't have to login to cpanel and then make it manually, I can use php to do save the file(s) but I need to test how the site design is.
But as I'm new to Java I don't have much knowledge of doing things.

Thanks,
Sreejith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt if there is a way to control the web browser without knowing or having its APIs. If the web browser you want to control does not provide an API for your java then it is impossible.

If you want to be able to fully control your web browser, you should try to develop plug-in using their APIs, not via JAVA.

If you just want to open a link in your default web browser, try this:

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://google.com"));
```

This code opens the url in your default web broswer. I used this to open lots of forum pages because it requires login session from my web browser and saves the pages all at once.

Comment: It helped thanks,

I was looking for a way to open a url and also to close that via Java.

Comment: I don't know how to close the pages. I normally use close all tabs function on Firefox.

Comment: I'm also not sure about that but I'm trying to figure out a way, Is it possible to use exec() for the loading chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using [cPanel XML api](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi) for what you are trying.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to test the saved files.

For saving the file(s), I have written a php script for that but I need to test the url's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Selenium [Here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

}

Add Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is it possible to develope an application which uses webdriver methods. Actually i asked a similar question here but not recived any solution. Link for my question is - Can we build an application using selenium webdriver? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536031/can-we-build-an-application-using-selenium-webdriver>