# Can we build an application using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, selenium-webdriver

I have created a framework which uses selenium webdriver and JUnit to update few websites on a regular interval. I am planning to give a UI and launch the application on google play. Can anyone tell me that is it possible to use selenium webdriver library , JUnit library,TEstNG and swing library to make an application which can be used by a end user?

Comment: selenium license is apache 2, so yes ;-)

Comment: check those other tools licenses to be sure

Comment: @Leo is that not an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check and agree with their licenses

- Selenium - apache 2 - http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/license.jsp
- JUNIT - EPL 1 - http://junit.org/license.html
- TestNG - apache 2 - http://testng.org/license/

You can redistribute these libraries in your product but you must pay attention to what each license says. But the answer is basically yes, and you're responsible for your software and can't blame them if there's any problem.

Comment: You can use and redistribute the code, following what is stated in each one's OSS license.